# How to monitor file/folder changes made while offline?

Tags: logging, monitoring, home-directory

We are 4 friends, working on a project. Everyone works separately on a computer (windows), and all the files are stored in a shared network drive in one of the PCs.

We want to monitor the changes made to files/folders in this drive. Changes like:

- New file/folder
- File/Folder delete
- File/Folder rename
- File Edit/Modify

and with these parameters:

- Date/Time of change
- User (who made the change)

I googled for this issue, and found many softwares. There are some problems with almost all of them:

1. Some of these softwares do not record the changes of the past offline time. For example, imagine I'm not at the office (and hence the file/folder monitoring software is not running on my pc). But my friends are working and making changes to some files/folders at the shared network drive. I go to the office, and I want to know exactly which files/folders have been changed while I was out. (since the last time I had run the monitoring software.) Most of these softwares have logs, but they only log event changes made after you run the software. They do not track the past.
2. We want to know which changes were made with which user/process/pc. Most of these file/folder monitoring softwares only track the changes, and do not recognize the user, specially over a shared network.

The only software I found for this purpose is ***[DirectoryMonitor](https://directorymonitor.com/compare.html)***. But its free version do not detect the user/process!

Do you know any other software?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill for your point. But I'm looking for a solution, not just a software.

Comment: <shrug> It's off-topic.

Comment: Search for the tag [version-control]